# What Device Class is a TV or Projector?

Tags: windows, winapi, device, guid

I am trying to figure out what class and GUID a TV or Projector belongs to in Windows OS?

Theres over 20 of them and I'm not sure which one a TV or Projector is part of. Here is the complete [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553426)

I suspect its one of the following HIDClass, Monitor, Media, etc.

DONT CLOSE THIS: I need to know this because knowing what class a TV is will tell me what GUID I need to use for the function SetupDiGetClassDevs(). This a relevant programming question!!

Comment: Looks like a valid question to me, even if it is a bit specialized, not an area of Win32 I'm familiar with. It might be useful to provide more context here - do you have access to one of these devices? Are you trying to detect attached hardware? Are you writing an app that uses one of these devices, or installs something for one, etc?

Comment: FWIW, seems like Monitor is most likely answer. HID is for things with inputs - keyboards, mice, controller boards with knobs and sliders, and the like. If the TV or Projector is just being used to display the contents of the screen as-is, that seems to be Monitor. On the other hand, if this was a TV that was displaying broadcast TV, and the device let you change channels or volume levels and/or capture that video, then it could be Media.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the differences between HID and USB device APIs:

```
API Namespace                                Access type

USB Windows.Devices.Usb                      exclusive read & exclusive write
HID Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice     shared read & exclusive write
```

Here are some CLSIDs for Device specific toolbars:

```
CLSID                                      Device
{29c93b94-45ef-44b3-8ad5-5ec104e0f9c6}     NEC LCD Projectors Toolbar

{b686afa8-7ca2-4c19-b9a8-ed364f126907}     AOL Television Toolbar
```

**References**

- [Windows Store device apps for internal devices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn265152)
- [Windows Media SDK, How to determine a device is a media center device?](http://www.mofeel.net/160-microsoft-public-windowsmedia-sdk/1079.aspx)
- [Multimedia Streaming on Microsoft Windows CE 3.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms834433.aspx)
- [CLSID List: Television](http://www.systemlookup.com/lists.php?list=1&type=name&search=television&s=)